# Datediff two columns different rows sql

Tags: sql-server

Hi I would like to please know how to calculate Datediff two columns different rows sql. This between days between the dispacheddate and next order date

I have the following

```
Id      orderid orderdate    dispacheddate 
A       1       10/04/2003   15/05/2003
A.      2.      17/06/2004   20/08/2004
```

I would like to add the datediff column.  So first row would be null

Next row shows 399

Please help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at `LEAD`/`LAG`? There are plenty of examples on SO, did you have a look at those? If so, is there a particular answer you didn't understand and we can try to explain further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your orderID is sequential, just join to the next ID

```
SELECT t.id, t1.id, datediff(t.dispacheddate, t1.orderdate) 
FROM myTABLE as t
LEFT JOIN myTABLE as t1 ON t1.id=t.id+1
```

Or using the much more modern LAG/LEAD as suggested in the excellent comment, assuming you are using SQL Server. If not the previous method is very vanilla and will work "anywhere".

```
SELECT id, datediff(LAG(dispacheddate,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY id) , orderdate) 
FROM myTABLE
```

Which is not only more robust against gaps in the ID sequence, but also likely much faster (to be tested)

Comment: Why perform 2 scans of the table though, when the analytical functions exist?